# WCF client certificate signing : how to?

Tags: wcf, certificate, signing, x509certificate

So I have a WCF service where I have various parts of the service contract with a ProtectionLevel of Sign. I set the credentials on the client side by choosing a certificate from the certificate store. This is fine.

However ....

1. Does this client certificate need to be in the 3rd party certificate store on the server for this to work?
2. If this is the case how can I configure a service which accepts any client certificate?
3. And finally how do I access the signing certificate within the implementation of the operations which require signed messages? Just the signing certificate subject name would do fine!

Thanks

Comment: why on earth would you ever want to move away from the default "encrypt+sign" ??

Comment: Demo purposes. Plus for a lot of messages you don't *need* the overhead of encryption, just a signature. Got it sorted anyway, will self answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah the joy of self answering.

So

1. "It depends". If you have
   ChainOrPeer validation then both the
   chain or the presence of the
   certificate in the trusted people
   store results in success. Only
   validating on chain obviously checks
   the chain, setting Peer validation
   uses the store, and None lets
   everything through.
2. Set the validation mode to none
3. The SecurityContext for the request
   contains an X509CertificateClaimSet
   which in turn exposes the
   certificate itself.